# api request response saved directly to google drive

Tags: javascript, python, api, google-drive-api, download

How can I save api request response directly to google drive ?

Example :

If I pull a csv report from a reporting API, now I need the file to be directly downloaded into my google drive instead of getting downloaded locally onto my system.

Comment: Your example is missing

Comment: Csv report case is the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Save to Drive Button](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive).

> The Save to Drive button enables your web site to allow users to save
>   files to their Drive account from an arbitrary URL via their browser.
>   The button is configured with a few attributes in a div tag in the
>   HTML markup, similar to how the [+1 button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/) is created.

Snippet of code from the documentation:

> The simplest way to display a Save to Drive button on your page is to
>   include the necessary JavaScript resource and to add the Save to Drive
>   button tag:
>
> ```
> <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
> <div class="g-savetodrive"
>    data-src="//example.com/path/to/myfile.pdf"
>    data-filename="My Statement.pdf"
>    data-sitename="My Company Name">
> </div>
> ```

This is how it works:

> The technology used to upload files is similar to that used by the
>   Google Drive web user interface. The file is downloaded to the user's
>   browser in parts and uploaded to Google Drive as data is received.
>
> This allows the user to save files that require some form of HTTP
>   authentication because the download is made in the context of the
>   user's browser.
>
> If the user navigates away from the page before the download is
>   complete, the data is discarded and no file is created.